# python combobox default current

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, combobox

I'm using Python 2.7.8 in Windows 1010. This one is really driving me crazy: I just want to have a default, preselected value for a `ttk.Combobox()` as soon as I grid it. This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class open_review_frame():
    def __init__(self, original):
        self.root = original                   
        self.review_frame = LabelFrame(original, text="review", bd=1, height=400, width=500)
        self.review_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W + N, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.rowline = 0

        self.review_type_val = StringVar()  
        self.review_type = ttk.Combobox(self.review_frame, width=12, textvariable=self.review_type_val, state='readonly')
        self.review_type['values'] = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
        self.review_type.current(0) 
        self.review_type.grid(row=self.rowline, column=2, sticky=W)

class main_frame():
    def __init__(self, original):
        self.root = original

        review_frame_test = open_review_frame(self.root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = main_frame(original=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Which draws an empty Combobox. What's puzzling is that if I put a replace text config with textvariable config it works perfectly:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class open_review_frame():
    def __init__(self, original):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = original

        self.review_frame = LabelFrame(original, text="review", bd=1, height=400, width=500)
        self.review_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W + N, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.rowline = 0

        self.review_type_val = StringVar()
        self.review_type = ttk.Combobox(self.review_frame, width=12, text= "", state='readonly')
        #self.review_type = ttk.Combobox(self.review_frame, width=12, textvariable=self.review_type_val, state='readonly')
        self.review_type['values'] = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
        self.review_type.current(0) 
        self.review_type.grid(row=self.rowline, column=2, sticky=W)

class main_frame():
    def __init__(self, original):
        self.root = original

        review_frame_test = open_review_frame(self.root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = main_frame(original=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I don't understand why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not guess what is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve by doing that. Nevertheless, if your aim is only to initialize the combobox then let us go:

> What's puzzling is that if I put a replace text config with
>   textvariable config it works perfectly

Actually, what happens is opposite to what you stated: the combobox fails to initialize using the `textvariable` option.

The explanation of this unexpected behavior is that because you are not using [`StringVar()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) properly. You need to set the value of `self.review_type_val` first. In your case, you want to set it to "a", so do this:

```
self.review_type['values'] = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
self.review_type_val.set(self.review_type['values'][0])
```

Then use `get()` to get that value in the combobox:

```
self.review_type = ttk.Combobox(self.review_frame, width=12, textvariable=self.review_type_val.get(), state='readonly')
```